# Manually (re)inserting the jquery datepicker values for two datepicker fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a lot of things going on in my datepicker file to achieve a few tasks.
1.) I needed to be able to block select dates or weekends (code not included below as it works)
2.) I needed a min and max date on each field to ensure the end user can't select anything less than, say, 3 days from the start date (see below)

My problem is that my website allows visitors to come BACK to the page they selected the dates on and change them if necessary to extend or shorten their stay. But when I come back, I can't seemingly pre-populate the fields properly so that my min/max date rules stay in-tact. How can I modify my code below to ensure my min/max rules are preserved while (re)inserting the values.

```
//CORE DATEPICKER FUNCTION
$(document).ready(function () {
$.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',minDate: +3,maxDate: "1Y +3D",changeMonth: true,firstDay: 1,changeYear: true,numberOfMonths: 2,constrainInput:true,beforeShowDay:nationalDays,});

$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    if (minDate) {minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 3);}//min nights required
    $('#datepicker_end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate || 1);
    days();
}}).val('12/11/2012');
$('#datepicker_end').datepicker({minDate: 1, onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');    
    if (maxDate) {maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1);}
    $('#datepicker_start').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate); // Date - 1    
    days();
}}).val('12/15/2012');
    $('#datepicker_start,#datepicker_end').change()
        });
```

Comment: not clear what the issue is. A demo in jsfiddle.net would help,. Can use jQuery UI CDN resources for the css

Comment: Sorry I meant to clarify what when I insert the dates like seen above, they do appear in the fields, but my min/max date rules aren't being preserved. Does that make more sense? I'll see if I can setup a jsfiddle of this.

Comment: demo defintely.. would be a lot easier to see what the issue is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XtS9B/1/ - this show how it works, but the min/date rules need to be kept in-tact when I return to the page. I need a way to insert the date while preserving my rules as seen in the demo. Thanks

Comment: what do I need to know or do to replicate the problem?

Comment: Imagine you selected two dates, and then went to another page. When you came BACK to the original page, how would I preserve the two dates you selected while maintaining my min/max rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to be able to run the same code as in the `onSelect` option. By wrapping that code in a separate function you can call the function when the page loads as well as in the `onSelect` handler.

```
function setEndMin(){
     var minDate = $('#datepicker_start').datepicker('getDate');  
        if (minDate) {
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 3);
        } //min nights requires
        $('#datepicker_end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate || 1);

}

$('#datepicker_start').val('12/11/2012').datepicker({       
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
       setEndMin();
    }
});
/* after create both pickers can process  min/max*/
setEndMin()
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/XtS9B/4/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. The weird part however is that when I take the exact same code off jsfiddle and put it on my site though, it fails to work - the datepicker fields don't work at all. Any ideas? I'm using literally the exact same code as in jsfiddle.

Comment: make sure is wrapped in `document.ready`, check for errors in console also

Comment: That was it, the document.ready was missing - Thank you! Sometimes I totally forget the basics. I appreciate your help on this!